# How to Roxygenize a single R script file?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I know how to roxygenise a package and the functions in it. But what if we are writing a single R script file (.R file) and we need to document it?

For example, I need to document this customPow function:

```
customPow <- function(x,y){
return(x^(y))
 }
```

I don't need to build a whole package for documenting this tiny simple function which would be an over-kill. How to roxygenise this function?

Answer (score 1):

The klmr/modules package has been replaced by the CRAN box package by the same author.

---

The klmr/modules package on github can do that -- note that this is not the same package as the modules package on CRAN even though it has the same name.

For an example, see [Using an R Markdown Document as a source for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650785/using-an-r-markdown-document-as-a-source-for-functions/35651887#35651887)